# openpyxl not writing dataframe to excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have some code to write a pandas dataframe to an excel sheet and for some reason it just doesn't do anything. I have used the same method previously with success.

```
book = load_workbook(os.path.commonpath(output)) #user is prompted for output file earlier in program
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.commonpath(output), engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Check', startrow = writer.sheets['Check'].max_row, index = False) # this should write the df out starting at the first row that doesn't contain any data in the excel sheet.
```

The program runs fine, just no output to the excel sheet when I open it. Any ideas?

Comment: this should not work, `load_workbook` in line one is spelled wrong

Comment: Sorry I fat fingered when typing, the computer I am coding on doesn't have internet so I can't copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need a `writer.save()` at the end of your code!